# Visual Studio 2013 : Can't run any C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

On visual studio 2013 , anytime that I try to run a C# Project I get an error :

```
 Error  1   The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
   System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uD955 at index 1217 to specified code page.
     at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1         comparer)
  at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild,        BuildRequestBlocker     blocker)
```

With VB.net projects everything is ok.
What can I do ?
Thank you !

Comment: The `EncoderFallbackException` is what you want to focus on. I Googled `encoderfallbackexception: unable to translate unicode character` and saw a few promising hits.

Comment: 1) Have you installed anything new before this happened? Either a Visual Studio update, a plugin, and add-in, or other software? Just asking to get the full picture. 2) Does the File > New Project (selecting a C# Library template for example) work?

Comment: I doesn't installed any update , and the file-New...... works ok.

Comment: Try building your files manually, using `csc.exe` (C# compiler) through command line.  If that's not working either, then it's not VS-related.

Comment: I try using CSC , but the build process shows some warnings that I'm missing some namespaces reference , but I know about these and I want to correct it , but inside the Visual studio when I try to build I don't get any of these errors because the build stops at the error that I have posted and doesn't display nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Scott Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx) , this can happen if you've got some corruption in your Windows PATH.

Try opening a Command Prompt, and enter PATH.

Have a look at the results to see if there is any garbage in there. If so, fix the PATH value and try to build again.

Comment: Thank you , I run the PATH ,but I don't see any problem. What do you you mean with "garbage" ? I have tried to post it here but is too long.

Comment: The example in the blog has a path containing question marks. The question mark is not a valid character for a Windows folder, and indicates that the PATH variable needs to be fixed.

Comment: % is okay. Perhaps the issue is with another environment variable. Try typing `SET > c:\temp\set.txt` at the command prompt (assuming you have a c:\temp folder), and then open the `set.txt` file in a hex editor (or open as binary in Visual Studio). Again, look for question marks.  SET will dump all the environment variables, not just PATH

Comment: That's unfortunate. To clarify, is the problem with all C# projects, or just one in particular?

Comment: There is a free tool called Rapid Environment Editor (it is "donate-ware") that I have used and is a much better way of looking at PATH and other environment variables. Use it and get rid of blank lines or things that show up in red in the PATH variable. (I don't develop or support this tool.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Opened Command Prompt and could see a series of "????". Copied the path environment variable to a notepad showed junk unicode content. Upon deletion of it, I could compile my projects. Thank you Scott Hanselman!!![image: Command Propmt]

[image: In notepad]